# cannot see recent files Nautilus (Ub 16.10)

Tags: nautilus

I am having a problem with recent files in nautilus: when clicking on it, i am getting the error:(loosely translated):

"Something went wrong! error message not managed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying"

When I am looking at the system journals, i am getting the list of messages below.

Do you have any suggestions of what it means, and how I could get it repaired? I like my recent files.

---

Here are the lists of message I am getting in journal system.

```
Nov  1 16:43:36 jeremie systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...

Nov  1 16:43:36 jeremie dbus[979]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'

Nov  1 16:43:36 jeremie systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd[1864]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd[1864]: Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd-recent[20814]: cannot open display: 

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd[1864]: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd[1864]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd[1864]: Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd-recent[20820]: cannot open display: 

Nov  1 16:43:42 jeremie gvfsd[1864]: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1633162/comments/15).

Adding `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` in the service file

```
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gvfs-daemon.service
```

and reboot/relogin solves it.

Comment: You should not edit `/usr/lib/systemd/user/gvfs-daemon.service` directly, but instead override it using `systemctl edit gvfs-daemon.service`.

Comment: @muru I had to do `systemctl --user edit gvfs-daemon.service` to get this to work.

Comment: @DavidL ah, yes, I forgot that this was a user service.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is already a bug report about it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1633162